# Solaris specific functions on a Solaris -> Linux migration

Tags: linux

I am migrating a Solaris 10 application to RHEL. The application uses certain Solaris-specific functions that I cannot find equivalent on Linux.

void double_to_decimal(double *px, decimal_mode *pm, decimal_record *pd, fp_exception_field_type *ps)
(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0213/6m6ne37t5/index.html)

Has anyone experienced this problem ? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

According to this source, there is no built in way in linux:

http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/operating-systems-and-server-administration/linux/0131871099/solaris-to-linux-reference-tables/app01lev1sec3